# FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am having an issue with our app being able to read from firebase firestore.
We have one app with 2 variations release and debug. It was working fine and I haven't changed anything.

The production/release is working fine.

I was working on a separate app that uses the same firestore and that one is also working fine(not yet released).

I googled the problem and most of them led me here to SO, but almost all the answers are to change the security rules to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

which is insecure. Our rules are set to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

FBAuthUI.kt

```
class FBAuthUI : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val COLLECTION_PATH_USERS = "Users"
    private val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 100
    private val RC_SIGN_UP: Int = 200
    private val TAG = "AuthUiActivity"

    private val TOS_URL = ""
    private val PRIVACY_POLICY_URL = ""


    // Choose authentication providers
    private val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build())


    private var userRef: CollectionReference? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.logo_red)
                        .setTheme(R.style.SignInTheme)
                        .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                                TOS_URL,
                                PRIVACY_POLICY_URL)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i(TAG, requestCode.toString())
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val idpResponse = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    if (idpResponse?.isNewUser() == true) {
            //signup code
            …
                    } else {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                if (idpResponse != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, idpResponse.error?.errorCode.toString())
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to sign in. Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LandingPageActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),{
…

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val homeFrag: Fragment = Home()
        val searchFrag: Fragment = SearchFragment()
        val profileFrag: Fragment = ProfileFragment()
        val bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.home_nav -> {
                        commitFragment(homeFrag)
                }
                R.id.nav_search -> {
                    commitFragment(searchFrag)
                }
                R.id.profile_nav -> {
                        commitFragment(profileFrag)
                }
                else -> {
                        commitFragment(homeFrag)
                }
            }
            true
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.home_nav
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    }

    private fun commitFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fm = supportFragmentManager
        val fragTransition = fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(fragment.toString())
        fragTransition.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit()
    }

    companion object {
        var bottomNav: BottomNavigationView? = null
        var CONTEXT: Context? = null
        private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

SearchFragment.java

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String COLLECTION_PATH_VENDORS = “BookStores”;

    private SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BookStore> bookstores;
    private String searchString;
    private ImageView searchImage;
    private EditText searchET;
    Boolean clickedCategories;
    ArrayList<BookStore> bkstore = new  ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new  ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private CollectionReference bookStoreRef;
    private String category;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Initialize view
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        recyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sr_recycler);
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        // Obtain Cloud Firestore instance
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        bookStoreRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_PATH_VENDORS);

        searchET = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        searchET.setCursorVisible(true);
        displayAll();


        SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getContext(), bkstore);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        return fragmentView;

    }

    private void displayAll() {
        Log.d("UserID Tag ", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        bookStoreRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    final BookStore aBookStore = new Bookstore();

                    aBookStore.setName(document.getString("Name"));
                   aBookStore.setCategory(document.getString("Category"));
                   aBookStore.setDescription(document.getString("Description"));
                   aBookStorek.setImage(document.getString("Image"));
                    aBookStore.setID(document.getId());

                    bkstore.add(DisplayResults(document));
                    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        });
    }

    private BookStore DisplayResults(QueryDocumentSnapshot document){
        BookStore aBookStore = new BookStore();

        aBookStore.setName(document.getString("Name"));
                   aBookStore.setCategory(document.getString("Category"));
                   aBookStore.setDescription(document.getString("Description"));
                   aBookStorek.setImage(document.getString("Image"));
                    aBookStore.setID(document.getId());

        return aBookStore.;
    }

}
```

Log returns:

```
D/UserID Tag: E4ARmAfe7aVG8oRiizHqWJatZlY2
W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(BookStores order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/ContentValues: Error getting documents.
    com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:117)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:588)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:424)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:104)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:577)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:461)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:109)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1$com-google-firebase-firestore-remote-AbstractStream$StreamObserver(AbstractStream.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:131)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:656)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:641)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:543)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:115)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:588) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:424) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:104) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:577) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:461) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:109) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1$com-google-firebase-firestore-remote-AbstractStream$StreamObserver(AbstractStream.java:119) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:131) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:656) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:641) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) 
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [WatchStream]: (9a4fb5d) Stream closed with status: Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets., cause=null}.
```

I am lost as to what the issue could be. I even tried changing the security rule but still got the missing permissions error.

Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the unexpected permission error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added some code where the issue may be occurring.
The Firestore exception occurs after logging in with the Firebase Auth UI

Comment: In `displayAll `, right before the call to `bookStoreRef.get()`, can you log `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` and show the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Log information has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the underlying issue was but after deleting google-services.json and re-downloading it, the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

### [Firestore security rules](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/authenticating-users-to-firestore-with-identity-platform-and-google-identities#create_firestore_security_rules)

1. Open the Firebase console, and click your project.
2. Click Firestore on the left-hand side of the screen.
3. On the Firestore page, click the Rules tab.
4. Replace the existing rules with the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents { 
  match /customers/{customerID} {
  allow read:
   if request.auth.uid != null
     && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "google.com"
     && request.auth.token.email == customerID
    }
  }
}
```

This rule grants read-only permission for the customers collection. The rule verifies that you have signed in through the Google sign-in provider that you configured in Identity Platform. It also makes sure that you can only retrieve documents with a customer ID that matches your email address.

**Note: Requests to Firestore are always evaluated against the database security rules, whether the request is for retrieving a single document, or for executing a query.**

5. Click Publish.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate clauses here:

```
allow read;
allow write: if request.auth != null;
```

For `write` you require the user to be authentication, but for reading you specify no condition, which apparently means reading it not allowed.

My guess is that you want the `if` clause to apply to reads and writes, which you can do with:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried this before but it does not work.